# FreeRDP CMAKE Error

Tags: cmake, relocation, against, libcrypto

Hello I am brand new to linux and i am trying to install FreeRDP. I keep getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(hmac.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [winpr/libwinpr/utils/libwinpr-utils.so.1.1.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [winpr/libwinpr/utils/CMakeFiles/winpr-utils.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After I type the "make" command. 
Sorry if this question has already been asked but i have thorougly searched stack overflow and havent found it. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

It wants you to add a parameter to ld: -fPIC
So if there is a line beignning with ld or gcc, just add it.
Mostly it is gcc and the parameter -shared already exists, so just add -fPIC behind it.